# How do I test the parity of a number (Floating Point - ARM)?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm doing a code and I want to check the parity of a number, to change the signal for minus when the number is odd and plus when even.

I tried to use VTST.F32 S0, #1.0, because I'w working with Floating Point as I use TST R0, #1 p.ex when I'm using Rn registers.
Is it that instruction for FP too, or I have to use another instruction?

FP - Fatorial.s(111): error: A1854E: Unknown opcode 'VTST.F32', maybe wrong target CPU?

This is the error that appears when I rebuild the code.

Comment: Please show your full code.

Comment: VTST.F32 S2, S11 ;TST with 1, like AND with 1, will zero out all bits but the rightmost one
 VMOV.F32 S3, #1.0 ; 
 VPUSH{S0-S1}
 VMOV.F32 S0, S3
 VMRS APSR_nzcv, FPSCR;
 BNE odd ; zero flag not set - meaning it's odd, and return -1 to register S3
 VMOV.F32 S3, S0
 VPOP{S0-S1}

Comment: Also, consult an instruction set reference. That will show you `VTST.F32` does not exist. `VTST.32` does exist, but it does not take a floating point constant as operand. Your logic is broken anyway. You don't know which bit to test in a float. If you have new information to add, use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56511006/edit).

Comment: If your float is known to hold an integer which fits into 32 bits, then convert it and check the LSB as usual. Otherwise, either the number is too big so you lost the LSB anyway or it's not a whole number so you can't tell if it's supposed to be even or odd.

Comment: So you want to test the oddness / evenness of the number *represented* by the float, not the bit-pattern itself?  Then you don't want a simple bitwise AND.  Also, it's confusing to call that parity.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_function in math and computing is whether a binary integer has an odd or even number of total set bits, not just the low bit.  i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity doesn't list simple odd/evenness as one of the meanings for the term.

Comment: @PeterCordes: "Even or odd" is the most basic interpretation of the word "parity" in mathematics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)) and it is on the Wikipedia disambiguation page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity.  Though I agree that in a computing context it can be ambiguous and should be clarified.

Comment: @NateEldredge: oh my bad, I missed that line in Wikipedia disambiguation page when trying to make my case for not using it in this context in computing.  I knew that was a usage.  Anyway, either usage makes little sense for a real number, but horizontal-xor parity on the IEEE754 bit-pattern still would make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I test the parity of a number (Floating Point ... )?

Your problem is not related to a certain CPU type or programming language, but it is a more general problem:

As Peter Cordes and Nate Eldredge already wrote in their comments, you want to check a **floating point** number for some property that is only defined for **integer** numbers.

If the floating-point value represents some integer value (like `25.0`) the parity of the number is well-defined. But what if the floating-point value is `25.6`?

- You might now say that it is guaranteed that the floating-point number will not have any digits after the decimal point and therefore the program does not need to be able to handle such cases.
- However, you might also say that the program should round to the nearest integer and perform the operation then:

  ```
  25.6 -> 26.0 -> 26 -> even
  ```
- or you always want to round down (towards minus infinity)
- or you always want to round towards zero.

Of course, all these cases will require different code.

You might convert a floating-point number to integer and then test for the lowest bit in the integer.

However, simply converting the floating-point number to integer will not always work:

You can store numbers that are much larger than the largest possible 64-bit integer value in a 32-bit floating-point variable.

I don't know how ARM CPUs will behave in this case; however they might return `0x7FFFFFFF`, which is an **odd** number, although such large floating-point values can only be multiples of 2 and therefore **even** integer values.

So what you could do is the following:

- Check if the floating-point value is inside the range that can be converted to integer
- If yes, convert the number to integer and perform the test
- If no, it must be a multiple of 2, so it is even

> error: A1854E: Unknown opcode `'VTST.F32'`, maybe wrong target CPU?

The "Bitwise Test" operation is a bitwise operation. The mathematical rules for bitwise operations are defined for integer (and maybe fixed-point) values only.

You would need bitwise floating-point operations that work on bits with the same significance instead of the same position in the bit pattern; this means that the C language expression `((float)i)&((float)j)` would lead to the same result as `(float)(i&j)`.

Theoretically it would be possible to perform `and` (and `test`), `or` and `xor` in software this way (`not` would not be possible), but I doubt that any existing CPU provides support for this in hardware.

Of course you can perform bitwise operations on the bit pattern that represents a floating point number. However, this will not lead to any useful result.

> can I do the conversion and put the result in a `Rn` result, I tried to do,
>
> -> `VCVT.S32.F32 R0, S2`

Unfortunately, I have not worked with ARM CPUs with an FPU before.

However, as far as I understand `VCVT` can only place the 32-bit *integer* value into a floating-point register and you have to use the `VMOV` instruction to copy it into an `Rn` register then.

Comment: As Jester says, ARM has [`VTST.32`](https://developer.arm.com/docs/dui0801/h/advanced-simd-instructions-32-bit/vtst) (but it doesn't take an immediate).  It produces a 0/-1 vector element, not integer integer condition code flags.  But x86 has [`(v)ptest`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ptest) which does set integer FLAGS based on a bitwise AND.  But of course these test the FP bit-pattern, not the number *represented* by the float.  Perhaps you should make it more explicit which "operation" you're saying CPUs don't provide.

Comment: "If yes, convert the number to integer and perform the test", can I do the conversion and put the result in a Rn result, I tried to do, -> VCVT.S32.F32 R0, S2, #S32, but I got a error->  FP - Fatorial.s(113): error: A1696E: Expected either 32-bit, 64-bit or 128-bit register expression.

Comment: @PeterCordes To check the parity of a number, the OP would need "Bitwise" operations that performs a test on bits with the same "physical" meaning. Example: `0x43000000 = 32.0`, `0x44000000 = 512.0`, `32 OR 512 = 544` and `544.0 = 0x44080000`. So he would need bitwise operations that work like this: `FLOAT_OR(0x43000000, 0x44000000) = 0x44080000`. (However he needs `and` or `test`, not `or`.)

Comment: All I'm saying is that you can check the low bit of the FP bit-pattern with a single instruction, exactly like the OP was trying to do in that quote.  (But that probably isn't what they really want.)  The way I read that section, you're conflating why their code didn't assemble with why it wasn't trying to do the right thing in the first place.

Comment: @LeonilSulude I've added a paragraph to my answer.

Comment: Looks a lot better, but maybe instead of talking about what it's "defined on", first just explain that it operates on the bits in the register (i.e. the FP bit-pattern in this case).  Or not, it's fine.  Anyway, bitwise AND on FP bit patterns can check the sign bit.  That's why x86 [`vtestps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vtestpd:vtestps) *only* sets flags based on the sign bits of the elements.  It's not useful *for parity*, though.  You could imagine some other use-cases like checking if the highest bit of the exponent field was set in any element => any element with magnitude >= 2.0.